# Emails not being delivered to server from certain mail servers: "domain has no valid mail exchangers"

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, mx-record

I'm having trouble with a server that I administer.

I've been told that a number of emails aren't coming through. These are consistently from certain people. Here's the bounce error that they receive:

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address failed:
>
> "example@fish-thecompany.com":
> domain has no valid mail exchangers

I don't know how to approach this. Obviously I have mail exchangers as we can send and receive email (usually) without a problem.

Is there anything I can do on our end or do I need to should I contact the postmaster for the domain that can't find the mail exchanger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that's your real domain (for which, many thanks), you have a problem with your MX record:

```
[me@lory ~]$ dig mx fish-thecompany.com
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
fish-thecompany.com.    86313   IN      MX      20 mail.fish-thecompany.com.
[me@lory ~]$ dig mail.fish-thecompany.com
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.fish-thecompany.com. 86300 IN      CNAME   fish-thecompany.com.
fish-thecompany.com.    86300   IN      A       109.228.0.95
```

But [RFC2181](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181) is very clear on the subject:

> 10.3. MX and NS records
>
> The domain name used as the value of a NS resource record, or part
> of    the value of a MX resource record must not be an alias.  Not
> only is    the specification clear on this point, but using an alias
> in either    of these positions neither works as well as might be
> hoped, nor well    fulfills the ambition that may have led to this
> approach.  This    domain name must have as its value one or more
> address records.    Currently those will be A records, however in the
> future other record    types giving addressing information may be
> acceptable.  **It can also    have other RRs, but never a CNAME RR.**

My guess is that some of your senders are using mail servers that are intolerant of violations of this particular RFC; as far as their servers are concerned, you really don't have any valid mail exchangers.  Fix that, make your MX-referenced host an A record, and this may well improve.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one out. I'll switch it to an A record and see how it plays out.

Comment: John, just in case you aren't familiar with local etiquette, if you're happy with an answer to your question, you should accept it by clicking the "tick" outline next to it.  That drives the SF reputation system both for you and the author of the answer, and it stops the question floating around forever like a querulous albatross.  My apologies if you already know this!

Comment: I do thanks, it just took a while to thoroughly test that this was the right answer. I've now set it as the answer

I appreciate the nudge though ;)

Comment: Thanks for taking it so well - and remembering to come back and cross the t, as it were.  Testing is **always** good!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your mail server, or dns setup does not correspond to the accepted rules.

http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx

Comment: This comment could be turned into a real answer with a bit more effort.